# Bokeh: Mapping points to images and displaying those images

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, visualization, bokeh

I have an (x,y) scatter plot where each point (x_i, y_i) is mapped to a .jpg file. My app is able to select a subset of points from the scatter plot, but I'd like to add a feature that displays the corresponding images in a panel underneath the scatter plot of the selected points. How is this possible in Bokeh?